# How to add black border to matplotlib 2.0 `ax` object In Python 3?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, border, aesthetics

I've been using style sheets in `matplotlib` lately.  I really like how clean the `seaborn-white` looks and I want to be able to add the border to other styles like `ggplot` or `seaborn-whitegrid`.

**How can I add a black border around my `ax` object from `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`?**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
from collections import *

Se_data = pd.Series(Counter(np.random.randint(0,10,100)))
with plt.style.context("seaborn-whitegrid"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    Se_data.plot(kind="barh", ax=ax, title="No Border")
with plt.style.context("seaborn-white"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    Se_data.plot(kind="barh", ax=ax, title="With Border")
```

[image]

In response to the answer below:

```
Se_data = pd.Series(Counter(np.random.randint(0,10,100)))
with plt.style.context("seaborn-whitegrid"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    Se_data.plot(kind="barh", ax=ax, title="No Border")
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('0.5')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color(None)
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('0.5')
    ax.spines['left'].set_color(None)
    ax.patch.set_facecolor('0.1')
    plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='0.2', linestyle='-')
    plt.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='0.2', linestyle='-')
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='0.7', which='both')
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='0.7', which='both')
    ax.yaxis.label.set_color('0.9')
    ax.xaxis.label.set_color('0.9')
    ax.margins(5)
    fig.patch.set_facecolor('0.15')
```

[image]

Comment: I think I'm missing something here. If you like the "seaborn-white" style, what's wrong with just using it instead of any other style?

Comment: I wanted to know how the borders are assigned so I can add it onto any plot

Comment: I think my answer below answers that. The borders are always there, just their color is more dark and the linewidth is thicker in the `seaborn-white` style.

Comment: The error you have in the updated version of the script is pretty self-explanatory, "margin must be [a number] in [the] range between 0 and 1". So don't use 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between the seaborn-whitegrid and the seaborn-white styles are

**seaborn-whitegrid**

```
axes.grid: True
axes.edgecolor: .8
axes.linewidth: 1
```

**seaborn-white**

```
axes.grid: False
axes.edgecolor: .15
axes.linewidth: 1.25
```

The following will thus provide identical plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
from collections import *

Se_data = pd.Series(Counter(np.random.randint(0,10,100)))
with plt.style.context("seaborn-whitegrid"):
    plt.rcParams["axes.edgecolor"] = "0.15"
    plt.rcParams["axes.linewidth"]  = 1.25
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    Se_data.plot(kind="barh", ax=ax, title="No Border")
with plt.style.context("seaborn-white"):
    plt.rcParams["axes.grid"] = True
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    Se_data.plot(kind="barh", ax=ax, title="With Border")
```

[image]

Comment: I had to add `plt.rcParams["axes.grid"] = False` in 'No Border' chart as my chart was apparently picking grid background as default.

Answer (score 24):

Take a look at [this](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch). What you're looking for are these two lines:

```
ax.patch.set_edgecolor('black')  

ax.patch.set_linewidth(1)
```

Comment: Instead of `ax.patch.set_linewidth('1') `,  what worked for me was `ax.patch.set_linewidth(1)`. It didn't accept a string as the width value.

Answer (score 9):

You probably want `ax.spines.set_color()`

These will give you a broad range of options for custom solutions:

```
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('0.5')
ax.spines['top'].set_color(None)
ax.spines['right'].set_color('0.5')
ax.spines['left'].set_color(None)
ax.patch.set_facecolor('0.1')
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='0.2', linestyle='-')
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='0.2', linestyle='-')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='0.7', which='both')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='0.7', which='both')
ax.yaxis.label.set_color('0.9')
ax.xaxis.label.set_color('0.9')
ax.margins(0.5)
fig.patch.set_facecolor('0.15')
```

For more details see: http://matplotlib.org/api/spines_api.html

Comment: ax.margins(5) should have been     ax.margins(0.5)

Comment: The background is still black :/ and the borders go away once I change it to white.

Comment: I wasn't setting them to anything specific; 1.0 is white; 0.0 is black, everything else is gray scale in between.  I left that for you to fiddle with to your needs; giving you the tools to customize.

Comment: For `ax.spines.set_color()`, I needed to set each spine individually (as in your code block), eg `[a.set_color("w") for a in ax.spines.values()]`.