# How to draw a frame on a matplotlib figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I want to show the frame in this figure.
[image]
I tried running the code below but it didnt work :

```
ax = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(True)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(True)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(True)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(True)
ax.plot(diff)
```

I also tried :

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

but it generates this error :

```
> File "runme.py", line 54, in autocorr_function
>     plt.tight_layout()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line
> 1406, in tight_layout
>     fig.tight_layout(pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad, rect=rect)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py",
> line 1753, in tight_layout
>     rect=rect)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py",
> line 326, in get_tight_layout_figure
>     max_nrows = max(nrows_list) ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Your help would be appreciated, thank you.

EDIT : Here's the code of the canvas :

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt from PyQt4 import QtGui 

class   Canvas(FigureCanvas):

     def __init__(self, parent=None):
         self.figure = plt.figure()     #plt.tight_layout(pad=4)
         FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.figure)
         self.setParent(parent)
         FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
         FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
```

Comment: It looks like you're not plotting within an orphan matplotlib figure, but within the canvas of some GUI. We need more information. tight_layout is a figure method to stretch the axes within the figure frame, it is not about the borders.

Comment: I added the code of the canvas, hope it puts more clarity.

Comment: For what do you need the canvas? Why don't plot it just using plt.plot(...)

Comment: I'm using Qt for GUI, I need a canvas to plot on the figure.

Answer (score 7):

The borders (or spines) are already visible, but white. You need to change the color as explained in this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43265998/1773344

example for some kind of gray:

```
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('0.5')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('0.5')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('0.5')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('0.5')
```

If you want the borders AROUND the axes, there is no simple solution. Except perhaps putting your axis inside an axis with adjusted borders as partially explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22608025/1773344

Answer (score 5):

The main point is that you seem to be using seaborn or at least the seaborn darkgrid style. If this is indeed desired, but you still want a border around the axes, you need to change the style.

```
plt.rcParams["axes.edgecolor"] = "black"
plt.rcParams["axes.linewidth"] = 1
```

This is (as @Wli mentions) explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43266852/4124317).

This is all independent of `tight_layout`. The reason why `plt.tight_layout()` produces the error shown cannot be determined for sure with the information at hand. However, you might in general be better off calling the figure's method than using `pyplot` in the GUI. SO you may try `self.canvas.figure.tight_layout()` instead.